# Trying to remove with if in python but not working?

Tags: python

I have used the below code to remove 20 from `list1`

```
list1 = [5, 20, 15, 20, 25, 50, 20]
if 20 in list1:
    list1.remove(20)
```

It doesn't remove instead if i do it this way first:

```
list1.remove(20)
```

but the above line only removes the first occurrence of it but when i run the if loop again, it removes the last occurrence too.

Why if loop doesn't work without that?

```
list1 = [5, 20, 15, 20, 25, 50, 20]
a = 20
if a in list1:
    list1.remove(a)
```

```
>>> print(list1)
[5, 15, 20, 25, 50, 20]
```

Comment: `.remove()` always removes the _first occurrence_ of whatever its argument is. Can you post the _full code_ that's giving you an error, and not just the one line?

Comment: Try the code from here https://www.includehelp.com/python/remove-all-occurrences-a-given-element-from-the-list.aspx

Comment: Please show the exact code and effects. What loop?

Comment: Just replace your `if` with `while` to make it remove all occurences of `20`

Comment: thanks. while loop solves but i wonder IF fails to do it. still stuck with MS excel.

Comment: `if` is not a loop. I think you meant `while` in the first place.